# Query syntax exception, table name is not mapped

Tags: hibernate

I'm using HQL query, pls see the below code.

Entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "COUNTRY")
public class Country implements Serializable{

private long countryCode;
private String countryName;
```

DAO:

```
public List<Country> getCountryList(){
    List<Country> resultList = null;
    System.out.println("in dao");
    Query query = getSession().createQuery(" from country ctry ");
    resultList =  query.list();


    return resultList;
}
```

app context.xml:

```
<beans:property name="annotatedClasses">
  <beans:list>
      <beans:value>com.test.in.ergy.entity.Country</beans:value>
  </beans:list>
</beans:property>
```

What might be the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my query from HQL to SQL and its working.
The query goes below..

```
String queryString = " select ctry.COUNTRY_CODE, ctry.COUNTRY_NAME from METRICS.COUNTRY ctry ";

    try {
        SQLQuery query = getSession().createSQLQuery(queryString);
        resultList = query.list();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use **createQuery** from **Query** class, Hibernate is case sensitive but regarding the class name that you are trying to retrive...not to the table

for example

Query query = session.createQuery("from Airplane"); 
will work if the name of the class is "Airplane"

Query query = session.createQuery("from AIRPLANE");
it will fail no matter if the table name in DB is AIRPLANE, because it will look for the class, not the table

Answer (score 0):

The entities in HQL queries are case sensitive.

Replace this:

```
Query query = getSession().createQuery(" from country ctry ");
```

for this:

```
Query query = getSession().createQuery(" from Country ctry ");
```

Extract from Reference Manual, chapter 14.1:

> With the exception of names of Java classes and properties, queries
>   are case-insensitive. So SeLeCT is the same as sELEct is the same as
>   SELECT, but org.hibernate.eg.FOO is not org.hibernate.eg.Foo, and
>   foo.barSet is not foo.BARSET.

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html

Regards

Comment: my query is using Country as the class name I have given is Country. Dont know whats going on.. NOt able to fix the issue

Comment: you could hve checked if  the table name is all in caps ? actual mysql table name? And yes hibernate is case sensitive